# How to set Texture readable from Image Capture by Camera in Android or IOS Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, android-camera, ocr, tesseract

I have try to build an app which need to use a camera to capture an image (Credit Card) and read the number from the image.

The number i need to read is **card number, expire month, and year.**

**I use a free asset from here :**

[Native Camera For Android IOS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/native-camera-for-android-ios-117802)

**to capture an image.**

Also i am using a **google tesseract form designspark here :**

[Tesseract OCR Unity](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/designspark-ar-app-ocr-module-for-unity)

**to recognize a text from image.**

But before trying to read a text from image i got a problem on reading a texture.

*For detail my code below :*

```
public void TakePicture(int maxSize)
    {
        if (NativeCamera.IsCameraBusy())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            NativeCamera.Permission permission = NativeCamera.TakePicture((path) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
                if (path != null)
                {
                    // Create a Texture2D from the captured image                    
                    Texture2D texture = NativeCamera.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize);                          

                    if (texture == null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                        return;
                    }

                    TesseractWrapper_And tesseract = new TesseractWrapper_And();
                    string datapath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "tessdata");
                    tesseract.Init("eng", datapath);

                    //Color32[] imageColors = texture.GetPixels32();
                    string result = tesseract.RecognizeFromTexture(texture, false);

                    //copy bufferColors to imageColors one by one with necessary logic.

                    Card_Number.text = result ?? "Error: " + tesseract.errorMsg;

                    // Assign texture to a temporary quad and destroy it after 5 seconds
                    GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
                    quad.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2.5f;
                    quad.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
                    quad.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, texture.height / (float)texture.width, 1f);

                    Material material = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
                    if (!material.shader.isSupported) // happens when Standard shader is not included in the build
                        material.shader = Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Diffuse");

                    material.mainTexture = texture;

                    Destroy(quad, 5f);

                    // If a procedural texture is not destroyed manually, 
                    // it will only be freed after a scene change
                    Destroy(texture, 5f);                   

                }
            }, maxSize);

            Debug.Log("Permission result: " + permission);
        }

    }
```

**I got an error on the line :**

> string result = tesseract.RecognizeFromTexture(texture, false);

**The error is :**

> AndroidPlayer(ADB@127.0.0.1:34999) UnityException: Texture '' is
>   not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You
>   can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   UnityEngine.Texture2D.GetPixels(UnityEngine.Texture2D,int,int,int,int,int)
>   at UnityEngine.Texture2D.GetPixels (System.Int32 miplevel) [0x0002b]
>   in <004fc436a9154f7fab4df9679445af6c>:0    at
>   UnityEngine.Texture2D.GetPixels () [0x00001] in
>   <004fc436a9154f7fab4df9679445af6c>:0    at
>   OCR_Test+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0 (System.String path)
>   [0x00040] in F:\Github\Tesseract_OCR\Assets\script\OCR_Test.cs:80
>   at NativeCameraNamespace.NCCameraCallbackAndroid.MediaReceiveCallback
>   (System.String path) [0x0001d] in
>   F:\Github\Tesseract_OCR\Assets\Plugins\NativeCamera\Android\NCCameraCallbackAndroid.cs:30    at
>   NativeCameraNamespace.NCCameraCallbackAndroid+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0
>   () [0x00000] in
>   F:\Github\Tesseract_OCR\Assets\Plugins\NativeCamera\Android\NCCameraCallbackAndroid.cs:19    at NativeCameraNamespace.NCCallbackHelper.Update () [0x0001d] in
>   F:\Github\Tesseract_OCR\Assets\Plugins\NativeCamera\Android\NCCallbackHelper.cs:21
>   (Filename: <004fc436a9154f7fab4df9679445af6c> Line: 0)

**The texture is not readable.**

*This is how and where the image captured and save to temporary disk.*

> Texture2D texture = NativeCamera.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize);

**and the file was found in here :**

> Image path: /data/user/0/com.Creativire.OCR/cache/IMG_camera.jpg

**Question :**

How to make the texture readable since the image is capture directly from the camera so we cannot set it from inspector ?

How to set the google tesseract from designspark just recognize the number ?

For note : *i have already try the designspark tesseract ocr with a file image save in the unity and it worked, just do not work when capture from camera directly.*

Any explanation from you is very appreciate.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

okay finally figured it out you just have to change the nonreadable property to false

```
Texture2D texture = NativeCamera.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize,false,true);
```